# Multi threading in borland

Tags: multithreading, include, pthreads, header-files, borland-c++

I'm programming c++ in Borland c++ 5.02. I'm trying to run this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define NUM 5

main()
{
  pthread_t t1, t2; /* two threads */

  void *print_msg(void *);

  pthread_create(&t1, NULL, print_msg, (void *)"hello");
  pthread_create(&t2, NULL, print_msg, (void *)"world\n");
  pthread_join(t1, NULL);
  pthread_join(t2, NULL);
}
```

But I get this error:

Info :Compiling C:\BC5\BIN\noname00.cpp

**Error:  noname00.cpp(2,2):Unable to open include file 'PTHREAD.H'**

Error:  noname00.cpp(8,15):Undefined symbol 'pthread_t'

Error:  noname00.cpp(8,15):Statement missing ;

Error:  noname00.cpp(12,18):Call to undefined function 'pthread_create'

I highlighted the main error which is caused by `'PTHREAD.H'`. *I checked the include folder for this file. It doesn't exist*. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Are you maintaining a product that requires the use of Borland C++ 5? Why else would one care to build anything using a product that has been released 17 years ago, a full year before C++98 standard?

Comment: Schools should really stop using Turbo and Borland C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borland's C++ toolchain doesn't include a pthreads library, nor does the Windows SDK.  You'll either need to use native Win32 thread APIs or get a 3rd party pthreads implementation for Windows.

Some options include:

- winpthreads.h: http://locklessinc.com/articles/pthreads_on_windows/
- pthreads-win32: https://www.sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/

I have no idea how well those things work with Borland C++ 5.x.

Another alternative is to use a toolchain that includes a pthreads implementation, such as TDM's MinGW toolchain:

- http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/

Answer (score 0):

your problem is `#include <pthread.h>`

- you need either copy all the pthread related files (*.h,*.c,*.cpp,*.hpp,*.lib,*.obj)
- into compiler include folder
- or add include path to it in your project/compiler settings
- or copy it locally to your project and change `#include <pthread.h>`  to `#include "pthread.h"`

So compiler did not find the pthread.h header

- so no datatype from it is known from compiler side (like pthread_t)
- therefore the rest of the errors...